# Standard output from MSTest, NUnit, MbUnit, xUnit.NET test runners

Tags: .net, unit-testing, build, nunit, mstest

How do you, in any of the common .NET testing frameworks MSTest, NUnit, MbUnit, or xUnit.NET, get the command line test runner to output a simple yes/no or true/false or 1/0 on whether all the tests passed or failed?

I'm open to workarounds like:

1. No output if all the tests passed, output if anything fails.
2. Count of tests that failed. I could look for zero or non-zero values.
3. Other things similar to #1 or #2

Which of these frameworks provide this kind of capability?

I did some playing with MSTest today and didn't see a way to make MSTest.exe output something I could use.

Comment: When you consider that MSTEST has been around for a few years, this is a surprising omission - unless it isn't important. Have you tried the /resultsfile switch?

Comment: I guess I could inspect the resultsfile. Seems like a lot of work. I'll give it a shot tomorrow though.

Answer (score 3):

They all output XML if you want (especially [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework)). You can use XSLT like [my version](http://preetsangha.blogspot.com/2008/05/decoding-ms-test-trx-file.html) for MSTest.

Comment: Should I take the total number of tests and compare that to "passed"? Will that avoid adding up the errors, failed, timeout, aborted, etc... ?

Comment: No there are lots of stats. I used Found as as example of what should have been attempted (removing ignored I think)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/), a framework and other tools (test runner, etc.) that MbUnit is built on, but that also handles the outputs MSTest, NUnit, RSpec, etc.

While that isn't exactly what you asked for, if you use the output from the Gallio test-runner, then you've got free support for the test formats - it's essentially a standard output.

Answer (score 0):

MSTest and most other runners return an exitcode you can check on.